# business and legal rules behind a psd to xhtml conversion service

Tags: xhtml, e-commerce, psd

Anyone know the legalities behind this type of online business?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of it depends on how you plan to read in PSD files, as its intellectual property belongs to Adobe. In contrast, there aren't any restrictions on XHTML that I know of.

I also second the idea of contacting a lawyer.